# Xcode (14 & 15) recompiles everything after any color change/image change in assets catalog

Tags: xcode, compilation

I have compile times very long with Xcode 15 each time I changed something in my assets (a color, a file). It seems Xcode recompiles the full app in this case. It(s an universal app (iOS/Mac) made in Swift. Around 250 swift files in the project.

So for a simple color change, I can wait 3 or 4 minutes...

I don't know:

- why this happens for the assets only (a code change in a file is much faster)
- how to verify what takes lots of time in the compile times

Any help or idea is welcome.